# IllegalArgumentException: You must supply an SQL string

Tags: android, sqlite

when I try to request informations from my sqlite database I get this error:

```
07-19 02:17:10.835: E/AndroidRuntime(689): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.bodprod.dkr/de.bodprod.dkr.MediNotmediList}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must supply an SQL string
```

My Database Request:

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> getAllNotmedis(){
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> notmediList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT medi_id, medi_wirk, medi_handel FROM dkr_medi_liste ORDER BY medi_wirk";
    Log.d("ALLNOTMEDIS",selectQuery);
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    HashMap<String , Object> notmedi_item;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            notmedi_item = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            notmedi_item.put("sql_id", Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            notmedi_item.put("wirk", cursor.getString(1));
            notmedi_item.put("handel", unescape(cursor.getString(2)));
            notmediList.add(notmedi_item);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return notmediList;
}
```

This line make the error:

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
```

Why I become this error? The database exist and is filled up with data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was in the `onCreate` section.

I tried to insert a blank line with `db.execSQL`.

I get the error on this line becaause `SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();` calls the `onCreate` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must supply an SQL string
```

Above exception occurs if you pass an invalid Sql Query statement in the `rawQuery` Method. There must be a problem in below statement:

```
= "SELECT medi_id, medi_wirk, medi_handel FROM dkr_medi_liste ORDER BY medi_wirk";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create  Database Adapter that will serve as the connection between your app and your database